# Run code at specific second remaining of each minute of real server time

Tags: node.js, timer

I want to run nodejs code at 30 second remaining in every minute of actual server time second & also after completing minute of real server time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a module named [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron). It's really easy to configure it to do what you want.

```js
const cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('30 * * * * *', () => {
    console.log(`This is going to be executed each minute at MM:30.
     It's ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} now.`);
});

cron.schedule('0 * * * * *', () => {
    console.log(`This is going to be executed each minute at MM:00.
     It's ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} now.`);
});
```

Please check out the docs as you can pretty much handle any time intervals like that.

PS: `node-cron` was inspired by a Linux utility called `cron`.
They are not 100% compatible (Linux cron doesn't have seconds) but you could check [this app](https://crontab.guru/) out to get an understanding of what you can potentially do.